# Unknown column 'user.id' in 'on clause'

Tags: mysql

MySQL query:

```sql
SELECT 
    *, 
    `message`.`status` as `message_status`, 
    `message`.`id` as `message_id`, 
    group_concat(response.response) as response, 
    group_concat(response.id) as response_id, 
    `message`.`user_id` as `sender` 
FROM `message` 
LEFT JOIN `pet_info` ON `pet_info`.`id` = `message`.`pet_id` 
LEFT JOIN `response` ON `response`.`message_id` = `message`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `user` as sender ON `user`.`id` = `message`.`user_id` 
LEFT JOIN `user` as receiver ON `user`.`id` = `message`.`owner_id` 
WHERE `user_id` = '6' 
AND `pet_id` = '6' 
GROUP BY `message`.`id`
```

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're aliasing the table:

```
LEFT JOIN `user` as sender
```

Which means, as far as the rest of the query is concerned, there is no `user` table.  There's a `sender` table.  So you need to use the alias in the `ON` clause:

```
LEFT JOIN `user` as sender ON `sender`.`id` = `message`.`user_id`
```